# Fourier series of a box function using sympy

Tags: fft, sympy, lambdify

I tried this code but i m getting an error. And If possible pls tell me how to lambdify the defined funct
CODE

```
from sympy.abc import x
from sympy import *

init_printing()
def func(y):
    if y>0:
        return 1
    elif y<0:
        return -1
    else:
        return 0
s = fourier_series(func(x), (x, -1, 1))
s = s.truncate(n=4)
s
```

"TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational"
this is the error im getting
Please help, 
Thank you.

Comment: You should use `Piecewise` or `Heaviside`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that sympy can only work with functions that are fully defined as a sympy expression. To emulate `if - elif - else`, [Piecewise](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#piecewise) can be used. There is also a special function, [Heaviside](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/special.html#heaviside), that directly corresponds to your given function. Default, `Heaviside(0)` is undefined. However, the value for `0` can be provided as a second argument.

Using the Heaviside function doesn't seem to work in this case:

```py
from sympy import Heaviside, fourier_series
from sympy.abc import x

s = fourier_series(Heaviside(x, 0), (x, -1, 1))
print(s)
```

This results in an unevaluated integral with which sympy can't do further operations:

```
FourierSeries(Heaviside(x, 0), (x, -1, 1), (Integral(Heaviside(x, 0), (x, -1, 1))/2, SeqFormula(cos(_n*pi*x)*Integral(cos(_n*pi*x)*Heaviside(x, 0), (x, -1, 1)), (_n, 1, oo)), SeqFormula(sin(_n*pi*x)*Integral(sin(_n*pi*x)*Heaviside(x, 0), (x, -1, 1)), (_n, 1, oo))))
```

Fortunately, with Piecewise, everything works as desired:

```py
from sympy import lambdify, Piecewise, fourier_series
from sympy.abc import x

s = fourier_series(Piecewise((1, x > 0), (-1, x < 0), (0, True)), (x, -1, 1))
```

The function can be [lambdified](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html) calling `lambdify(x, s.truncate(n=4))`, and then be used for example to draw curves via matplotlib:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for k in range(1, 7):
    s_np = lambdify(x, s.truncate(n=k))
    xs = np.linspace(-1, 1, 500)
    plt.plot(xs, s_np(xs), label=f'$n={k}$')
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=True)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Thank you so much , that really helped ,  s = fourier_series(Piecewise((1, x > 0), (-1, x < 0), (0, True)), (x, -1, 1)).      In this line what does (0,True) signifies?

Comment: As explained in the [already linked manual](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#piecewise), `Piecewise( (expr1,cond1), (expr2,cond2), …, (exprN,True) )` tests the conditions one by one, and the expression corresponding to the first condition that results True will be the returned. It is similar to `if cond1 return expr1 elif cond2 return expr2 ... else return exprN`.  In the code, the last condition is always `True`, so `0` will be returned in case neither `x > 0` nor `x< 0`.

Comment: Really sorry, Im new to stackoverflow, Your ans really helped man!

Comment: s = fourier_series(Piecewise((-2.0*t,  -2.0<t<0.0), (2.0*t, 0.0 < t <2.0), (0, True)), (t, -2.0, 2.0))   gives Truth Value error.

Comment: Sympy gets confused with `-2.0<t<0.0`. You can replace it with `And(-2.0 < t, t < 0.0)`.  Also, better use `2` instead of `2.0`, so `s = fourier_series(Piecewise((-2 * t, And(-2 < t, t < 0)), (2 * t, And(0 < t, t < 2)), (0, True)), (t, -2, 2))` should work better.

Comment: @qqqqq Sympy together with matplotlib also get confused lamdifying the series when `k = 1` (giving a constant 2 which when called on an array gives a constant instead of a constant array). You can draw the curves for k starting at 2.